# Excel VBA - read cell value from code

Tags: excel, vba

task to send email from excel.
Below is the example column. How I can get the email value from the loop?
Thanks

[image]

Here is my code :

```
   Dim rng As Range
   Dim row As Range
   Dim cell As Range
   Dim mydate As Date
   Dim myDiff As Long
```

Set rng = Range("E5:E17")
Set rng2 = Range("F5:F17")
Dim cell2 As Range

Dim i As Integer
i = 5

For Each row In rng.Rows
  For Each cell In row.Cells

```
MsgBox cell.Value
mydate = cell.Value
myDiff = DateDiff("d", Date, mydate)

Set rng2 = Range("F" & i)
For Each cell2 In rng2
 MsgBox cell2.Value
Next cell2
```

If myDiff > -8 And myDiff < 8 Then
  aEmail.Send
End If

i = i + 1
  Next cell
Next row

Comment: Well, you're looking at `Range("E5:E17")`, and your email addresses are in column `F`, so it looks like you should just read the value from column `F` when you need the email. What exactly is your question?

Comment: yes. above script is only get date value only. I need the email value in the loop also. So that if the datediff is more than 8, email will send to the respective email.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I think you need this ..

```
Dim n as Integer   

For n = 5 to 17
  msgbox cells(n,3) '--> sched waste
  msgbox cells(n,4) '--> type of treatm
  msgbox format(cells(n,5),"dd/MM/yyyy") '--> Lic exp
  msgbox cells(n,6) '--> email col
Next
```

Comment: No, i just want to get the email value in the loop.

Comment: Hm... i already update my code. BUT, how do i get only the email column for the current row only?

Comment: yes. that i want! I also got already. Your code more simpler. Thanks!