# VBA - Copy as Path

Tags: vba, excel

I need help with a coding requirement that I've not previously experienced. I just browsed a similar issue raised here a couple of years ago - [VBA to Copy files using complete path and file names listed in Excel Object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25025009/vba-to-copy-files-using-complete-path-and-file-names-listed-in-excel-object). 
My issue is similar but somewhat simpler than the OP.

I have a number of folders that each contain about 100 small .csv files; for each folder I need to copy the path for each file to an open worksheet. Each folder of .csv files has its own associated workbook.

As one example, the open workbook is `F:\SM\M400AD.xlsm` and the active worksheet is `CSV_List`. The folder containing the .csv files is `F:\SM\M400AD`.
Doing it manually, my sequence is then:

Open folder `F:\SM\M400AD`

Select all

Copy path

Paste to `Range("B11")` of worksheet `CSV_List`

When I do it manually, as described above, I get a list that looks like:

```
"F:\SM\M400AD\AC1.csv"
"F:\SM\M400AD\AC2.csv"
"F:\SM\M400AD\AE.csv"
"F:\SM\M400AD\AF.csv"
"F:\SM\M400AD\AG.csv"
"F:\SM\M400AD\AH1.csv"
"F:\SM\M400AD\AH2.csv"
"F:\SM\M400AD\AJ.csv"
```

and on down the page until I have a list of 100 paths. This single column list is then pasted into worksheet `CSV_List`, starting at `Range("B11")`.

I need to automate this and would be grateful if a VBA guru could kindly code this for me.

Comment: _if a VBA guru could kindly code this for me._ that's not how SO works.  Please familiarise yourself with the [help]

Answer (score 1):

Such of question has been asked before, for example:

[Loop through files in a folder using VBA?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10380312/loop-through-files-in-a-folder-using-vba)
[List files in folder and subfolder with path to .txt file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20219362/list-files-in-folder-and-subfolder-with-path-to-txt-file)

The difference is you want to "automate" it, which means you want to execute code on workbook `Open` event.

How to achieve that?

1. Open `F:\SM\M400AD.xlsm` file.
2. Go to **Code pane** (`ALT`+`F11`)
3. Insert new module and copy below code

   ```
   Option Explicit

   Sub EnumCsVFilesInCurrentFolder()

       Dim sPath As String, sFileName As String
       Dim i As Integer

       sPath = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\"
       i = 11
       Do
           If Len(sFileName) = 0 Then GoTo SkipNext
           If LCase(Right(sFileName, 4)) = ".csv" Then
               'replcae 1 with proper sheet name!
               ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1).Range("B" & i) = sPath & sFileName
               i = i + 1
           End If

   SkipNext:
           sFileName = Dir(sPath)
       Loop While sFileName <> ""

   End Sub
   ```
4. Now, go to `ThisWorkbook` module and insert below procedure:

   ```
   Private Sub Workbook_Open()
       EnumCsVFilesInCurrentFolder
   End Sub
   ```
5. Save and close workbook

The workbook is ready to use. Whenever you open it, `EnumCsVFilesInCurrentFolder` macro will be executed.

Note: you have to change above code to restrict the number of records.

Comment: @TobyAllen, Thank you very much for improving my answer.